# The result gets changed every where

Tags: javascript, php, onchange

This is my view please have a look :

```
<div class="form-group target" id="tools" >
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="col-lg-6"> <select class="form-control" style="width: 100%" name="tool_id[]" id="toolss" onchange="tool(this)" required>
      <option value="">Select</option>

      </select></div>

    <div class="col-lg-3">  
      <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="quantity[]" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3" id="avail">  
      <p class="available">0 available</p>
    </div>

    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger addel-delete"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my script :

```
function tool(sel)
{
  var tools=sel.value;

  alert(tools);

  var url='<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/tool/ajax_available';
  $.post(url, {tools:tools}, function(data){  
    alert("Value: " + $(".available").html(data));
  });
}
```

The problem is whenever I goes on selecting values from the select box the corresponding value and all the previously selected values are becoming same.
the image am showing here.

*[Valid XHTML http://spdc.in/demo/spectra/assets/images/s-tool1.PNG](http://spdc.in/demo/spectra/assets/images/s-tool1.PNG).*

Comment: `$(".available")` will search for every element with class `available` in the page and not only in the `tools` container the changed `<select>` is in.

Comment: k.but for getting exact result what i should have to do

Comment: Have a look at Zakarias answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vk3qw09f/41/)**.

**Problem :** When you use `.available` selector it will affect all the element with class `available` in your document.

**Suggested solution :**

The `id` should be unique in the same document so if you've multiple `tools` you should replace the `id` with a class for the valid structure :

```
<div class="form-group target tools">
```

Then you should refer to the current element in your selector, so use :

```
$(sel).closest('.tools').find('.available').html(data);
```

Hope this helps.